# Drupal: basic page's body new line doesn't work

Tags: php, drupal, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I have wysiwyg module and ckeditor installed on my drupal site.
When I type some text of few lines, the result shows everything thing in one line.
Can anyone tell what could be the problem.
When I press preview before saving, it shows the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the input format you selected is "full html", hopefully this will work ...